# Can I use crystal + driver(op-amp) to generate waveform

Tags: operational-amplifier, generator, crystal

Now I need to design a high frequency generator(about 2MHz). Can I just use a 2MHz crystal + low offset current op-amp to produce a +-15V,10mA square wave signal?

If not, what would be the problems in my idea? And what structure I should use to generate such signal?(+-15V,10mA output, the actual value is not matter if not higher than +-18V; and the frequency is 2MHz, about 10% accuracy, and the rising and falling time are around 5% of the signal period time)

Comment: What is the slowest rise and fall time you are prepared to accept? How important is that it is exactly 15V up and down - how about putting a tolerance on this (and don't say the op-amp should saturate against 15V rails because it won't work). The devil is in the detail.

Comment: Thank you. But what do you mean by rise and fall time? can you explain a little

Comment: @billyzhao To put it another way: how "sharp" do the edges of the output square wave need to be?

Comment: @duskwuff I think 5%~10% of the signal period

Comment: ... and the accuracy of the +/-peak signals?

Comment: @Andyaka not so matter, may be +-20% is still ok.

Answer (score 1):

You need a special amplifier to achieve rise times of <5% of 2MHz with a 30 V swing. This means for this assuming potion, slew rate is 30V/(5%*500ns) or greater than 1000 V/us, which we call in electronics world "damn fast". .

Search for this to find a solution. Note that the power of your load is 30Vx10mA=300mW is small, but the critical factor is your load capacitance.

... perhaps a 74LVC04 5V Xtal osc. driving a logic level common gate FET amp.with +5 to gate and drive source with drain to load and 30V

```
Vs = +-15 V   AD810
Closed-Loop –3 dB BW
Gain R FB R G ...(MHz)
+10 270 Ω 30.0 Ω 65
–10 249 Ω 24.9 Ω 65
```

Comment: Thank you for you advice. I have found AD810. The slew rate is 1k V/us. So is it suitable in my case?

Comment: no that limits you to Av=2

Comment: @TonyStewart it will work if his oscillator fed into that device as an input i.e. use it as a gain of 2 stage however, I still don't think it'll cut the mustard.

Comment: @TonyStewart but a graph in the AD810 datasheet says the slew rate could reach nearly 1000V/us @(+-15V supply,gain=+10,Rl=400ohm).

Comment: sure ok if 50MHz BW is good enough and you have a great layout V S = 615 V
Closed-Loop –3 dB BW
Gain R FB R G (MHz)
+1 1 kΩ 80
+2 715 Ω 715 Ω 75
+10 270 Ω 30 Ω 65
–1 681 Ω 681 Ω 70
–10 249 Ω 24.9 Ω 65